# Get Thread's Start Address for External Process in C#

Tags: c#, windows, memory-address

I've setup a simple C# program.
I have imported from `kernel32.dll` [`OpenProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320(v=vs.85).aspx), [`ReadProcessMemory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`WriteProcessMemory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681674(v=vs.85).aspx).

I've acquired an external process into a [`Process`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

How can I get the [`StartAddress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processthread.startaddress(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) for **Thread #0** for that specific [`ProcessThread`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processthread(v=vs.110).aspx)?

```
Process process = Process.GetProcessesByName("Calculator")[0];
if (process == null) {
    Console.WriteLine("Process not found");
    return;
}

foreach (ProcessThread thread in process.Threads) {
    Console.WriteLine(thread.StartAddress);
}
```

The result of the code above is:

```
-157479632
-157479632
-157479632
-157479632
0
-157479632
-157479632
-157479632
-157479632
-157479632
-157479632
-157479632
```

Why are there some 0's and the rest are the same and all negative?

Comment: That's not possible.  It used to work in the previous major version of Windows, version 5.  Aka Windows XP and 2003.  Internal kernel changes broke it.  Avoid asking an XY question, it is impossible to tell why it matters.

Comment: @Hans Passant ~ What.

Comment: You may learn more from this code: Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();

            Array.ForEach(processes, delegate(Process p) {
                foreach (ProcessThread thread in p.Threads)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(p.Id + ": " + thread.StartAddress);
                }
            });

            Console.ReadLine();

Comment: I think it may be some insufficient privileges. Maybe I need `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION`? But the problem is, when I call `thread.StartAddress`, there is no chance for me to use any privilege enums.

Comment: @Anthony McGrath, okay interesting... every single process on my computer shows a `thread.StartAddress` of `-157479632` (10% have a `thread.StartAddress` of 0) --- **But**, process with ID of 4 and 0 shows a normal looking values with `4: 2024627296` and `0: 2021639600`. --- Process ID 4 is `System` and ID 0 is `System Idle Process`

Comment: Yeah, only some processors with username `SYSTEM` show normal StartAddresses.

Comment: @Acidic - at first always print address in hex format as pointer. don't know how do this in c# but in c/c++ this is %p format. about start address - in thread object -stored 2 different addresses : `StartAddress` (your code try print it) and `Win32StartAddress` - it more informational - for get it need call `PVOID pv;
  ZwQueryInformationThread(hThread, ThreadQuerySetWin32StartAddress, &pv, sizeof(pv), 0)`. also in some case this address part of union field and can be overwritten

Comment: @RbMm I'm not sure how I could impliment `ZwQueryInformationThread` in C#. I don't know how to match the variable types (HANDLE, THREADINFOCLASS, etc.)

Comment: in some way how you call `ReadProcessMemory` for example

Comment: @RbMm I tried, but I got stuck when it came to setting up the parameters.I don't understand what `THREADINFOCLASS`, `PVOID`, `PULONG` would be in C#

Comment: @Acidic - `THREADINFOCLASS` declared in `ntddk.h` - `ThreadQuerySetWin32StartAddress = 9`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in thread object (struct `_ETHREAD`) exist 2 different start address - `StartAddress` - this is address from which thread begin execute after walk throughout DLLs via `LdrInitializeThunk`. also exist second address - `Win32StartAddress`. sense of this address - when we create thread by win32 function [`Create[Remothe]Thread`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682437(v=vs.85).aspx) (or it shell) - win32 level set common thread `StartAddress` to `ntdll.RtlThreadThreadStart` (name of this function is depend from windows version, say on xp - another name) and actual *lpStartAddress* is passed to `Create[Remothe]Thread` as parameter. the `RtlThreadThreadStart` already call actual *lpStartAddress*. the *lpStartAddress* and stored in `Win32StartAddress`.

because most threads created via win32 `Create[Remothe]Thread` - all they have the same `StartAddress` (for have another `StartAddress` we need direct call low-level api like `RtlCreateUserThread`. also in *System* process - the `StartAddress` is actual thread start address in kernel)

when you use code

```
foreach (ProcessThread thread in process.Threads) {
    Console.WriteLine(thread.StartAddress);
}
```

you got the `StartAddress` - and absolute normal that you in most case give the same address. in some case you can got 0 or another incorrect value - because in some version windows `StartAddress` saved in union with another member and can be overwritten.

for get the `Win32StartAddress` you must have opened thread handle with `THREAD_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` or `THREAD_QUERY_INFORMATION` and call `ZwQueryInformationThread` with `ThreadQuerySetWin32StartAddress`

```
    PVOID pv;
    ZwQueryInformationThread(hThread, ThreadQuerySetWin32StartAddress, &pv, sizeof(pv), 0);
```

and about `all negative?`

because you incorrect print the thread address - pointer. you print it as signed integer. but you must print it in hex as pointer with `%p` format

Comment: This helps me a lot, but I still haven't managed to use `ZwQueryInformationThread` in C#.

Comment: @Acidic - i don't know c# but if you can call say `WriteProcessMemory` and `OpenProcess` from `kernel32.dll` - in what problem call this api from `ntdll.dll` ? first you must open thread by `OpenThread` with `THREAD_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` and then call `ZwQueryInformationThread` / how you call another native api ?

Comment: I've switched to writing my program in C++! Thanks heaps for the help though